# Show all week days in chart in Kendo Chart?

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to achieve a behaviour as below:

[image]

But my chart is shown as below. It has only one record in the json array

[image]

Even if there is no data for some days on a week, i need to show the weekdays as in the first image.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8WjKV/5/)

```
$("#kk").kendoChart({
            dataSource: {
                data:_data
            },
            seriesColors: ["Orange"],                

            seriesDefaults: {
                type: "column",
                gap: .5,
                overlay: {
                    gradient: "none"
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: "weight",
                field: "weight",
                categoryField: "createddate",
                aggregate: "avg",
            }],

            categoryAxis: {
                type: "date",
                baseUnit: "weeks",
                labels: {
                    rotation: -45,
                    dateFormats: {
                        weeks: "ddd"
                    }
                },
                majorGridLines: {
                    visible: false
                },
                majorTicks: {
                    visible: false
                }
            }                        
        });
```

Comment: Can you show your markup and JSON?

Comment: @Andrew : Updated my question with a link to fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So all you need to do is append end points to your array of data. You can do this in your controller that returns data or later with JavaScript (which will cause you to redraw the chart unless you catch the data before you place it in the chart.)

You will need to make an array of Json objects like the rest of your data. It may look somthing like this. startDate and endDate being your chosen range.

```
function endPoints(){
return [{createddate:startDate,weight:0},{createddate:endDate,weight:0}];
}
```

You can append these data points with something like this.

```
function addDataToChart(data) {
  var ds = $('#kk').data('kendoChart').dataSource;
  ds.data($.merge(data, endPoints()));
  //You can use ds.data() if you want to use the data that is already in the chart
}
```

In my own Dashboard project I would get the data with my own Ajax calls and append endPoints before it was placed in the chart. The full ajax function could look like this.

```
$.ajax({
  url:'URLtoReturnData'
  dataType:'json',
  success:function(data){addDataToChart(data);},
  error:function(e){errorHandler(e);}  
});
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

This a workaround to get dates with no values to be displayed. The workaround is to have weight as 0.000000000000000001 for dates that has got no weight values against it. Also i have updated the category baseunit to days and added some sample data for you so that you can have a look at it how it appears. What you can do is put 0.000000000000000001 for dates that have 0 value against it when you are returning the JSON Markup. Code as below:

```
       @*Sample Data:*@

       var _data=[{"weight":149.91,"createddate":"8/1/2014"},
       {"weight":0.000000000000000001,"createddate":"8/2/2014"},
       {"weight":200,"createddate":"8/3/2014"},
       {"weight":0.000000000000000001,"createddate":"8/4/2014"}]

       $("#kk").kendoChart({
            dataSource: {
                data:_data
            },
            seriesColors: ["Red"],                
            seriesDefaults: {
                type: "column",
            },
            series: [{
                name: "weight",
                field: "weight",
                categoryField: "createddate",
            }],
            categoryAxis: {
                type: "date",
                baseUnit: "days",
                labels: {
                    rotation: -45,
                    dateFormats: {
                        days: "ddd"
                    }
                },
            }                        
        });
```

Please have a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NitinMall/8WjKV/16/) for the same to see output

Comment: But I have only one record in the JSON array in my example.

Comment: So do you want to display all the others days of the week?

Comment: Exactly, even if the data is missing for that day (for eg: sun, mon etc) i want to show them on the category axis

Comment: In your JSON, rather than getting the createddate, can you get the day i.e. Wed. If you can update that then you can set the week days as static in the category axis, wait i will provide you an updated JSFiddle for it.